# Navigate to a list of directories without using loop in r

Tags: r, loops, apply

I want to navigate to specific directories and process the files found within the folders. I have many models ('`models`') and experiment ('`exps`') combinations that I want to navigate to their specific directory and carry out processing on the data held within.

I can do this using:

```
models<- c("model1","model2","model3")
exps<- c("exp21","exp42","exp54")
for (g in 1:length(models)){
  gfilepath = file.path("C:/Users/Documents/data/models",models[g],"Netcdfs")
  for (r in 1:length(exps)){
    rfilepath =  file.path(gfilepath,exps[r])
    list.files(rfilepath)
#Do my processing here
  }
  
}
```

Can I do this without using a loop? I was looking at trying to use apply using just one vector of strings to incorporate in the file path:

```
test<-apply(c("model1","model2","model3"),function(x){
filename=file.path("C:/Users/Documents/data/models",x)
})
```

but I got:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

I thought the 'file.path' would be the function?

Is it possible to navigate to the specific folders another way (besides for the loop)? I think maybe using a recursive option in a function may help, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The help file to list.files which can be accessed using `?list.files` contains the argument you require, namely `recursive = T`

```
list.files(all.files = T, recursive = T)
```

Comment: That will give me all the files in the top folder of the directory (or wherever I have set my working directory to), but I will need specific combination of filepaths to give me the folders only for that particular directory one at a time. For example, I'll need all the files in `C:/Users/Documents/data/models/model1/Netcdfs/exp21`, then I would need all the files in `C:/Users/Documents/data/models/model1/Netcdfs/exp42` (`model` and `exps` pulled from the vector declared above.

Comment: I can use the pattern option to filter out the files I want using your suggestion, but it also returns the subdir name in the file list? i.e.list.files(all.files = T, recursive = T,pattern="exp21.nc",include.dirs = F) returns a file list including: `dataexp21.nc` as well as `exp21/dataexp21.nc`